# Fastest sine of a large power of 2

Tags: computational-complexity, random-functions, chaos

What is the fastest known way to calculate $\sin(2^{n})$ for large integer $n$?

I only need the highest few bits to be correct.  I suspect that the compute time required
scales with $n$ (and actually is a little slower-than-linear because more bits are needed
within a longer computation to target a final numerical precision), but hoping here for
something faster-than-linear, like the [trick of repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) used for analogous problems in
discrete chaos.

If faster-than-linear computation here is impossible, can you prove it?

---

Here is a benchmark for my 3GHz (though RAM access is my bottleneck) PC using just one core, just inverting a precalculated $\pi$ and getting tail bits (see François Brunault's comment):

```
sin(2^(10^ 7)) = 0.4256378565...   computed in    0.5  seconds
sin(2^(10^ 8)) = 0.4342849634...                  5    seconds
sin(2^(10^ 9)) = 0.5828461690...                 60    seconds
sin(2^(10^14)) = ?                                6     months
```

A new PC would probably post 10x faster times, but 10^14 is the limit of $\pi$ bits that have been calculated, so further values will take much more (still slower-than-linear) work for this method (for comparison, calculating 10^9 bits of $\pi$ took 1400 seconds on my PC).  It's interesting that the [fastest algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm) to calculate $\pi$ first calculates our desired $1/\pi$, so inversion is actually not needed.  For more generality, I wonder whether we could extract just the tail bits of any power of any natural constant (like $\pi$, or $e$, or $\sqrt2$) faster-than-linearly ([BBP's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) gives some hope, but even it is slower-than-linear).

Comment: for linear scaling you could calculate this recursively $a_{n+1}=(a_n)^2$, $a_0=e^i$ and then take the imaginary part; or compute $2^n$ mod $2\pi$ and then take the sine of the resulting small number.

Comment: Perhaps using double angle identities is helpful: $s_n = \sin(2^n)$, then $s_n = 2s_{n-1}(1-2s_{n-2}^2)$.

Comment: @Aeryk I tried your suggested recursion method and a power of a million, for example, requires a million bits of precision in the s.  So, it's currently O(n^2) time complexity though I want to be even faster than linear O(n).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The "mod 2pi" method seems fastest even when I include calculation of pi itself in the time (benefited by O(n*log(n)^3) "pi tricks" instead of the direct O(n^2) methods I would otherwise use for pi).  With pi precalculated, I think we are at O(n*log(n))...still hoping for something faster.

Comment: Be careful because you're going to need some error analysis to prove that what you have computed has enough correct significant digits. Merely finding a formula isn't enough.

Comment: Here is a PARI/GP implementation: {s(n)=localbitprec(n+128);my(x=((1/Pi)<<(n-1))%1);sin(2*Pi*x);} It computes $\sin(2^{10^8})$ in 35 seconds, giving 0.43428496345181135524413277885026106701 (the precision of the output is roughly 128 bits). If $\pi$ is precomputed then it just takes around 2 seconds (the time needed to invert $\pi$). Your question is rouhgly equivalent to determining the bits of $1/\pi$ in the range $[n,n+h]$, if you want $h$ bits of accuracy.

Comment: Did you try the Chudnovsky algorithm for $\pi$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm

Comment: Somewhat related: Paul Olum once stumped Richard Feynman, who was boasting how he could accurately and quickly estimate any mathematical quantity that could be stated in ten seconds, by challenging him to estimate $\tan(10^{100})$.  https://books.google.com/books?id=j42RD66g72oC&pg=PT254&lpg=PT254&dq=feynman+olum+tangent&source=bl&ots=fFoe32zQXp&sig=ACfU3U2E81n0xzOG6gOptYEElV4P-Td_gA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE6-rswOn1AhVVI0QIHfGvBBI4ChDoAXoECCsQAw#v=onepage&q=feynman%20olum%20tangent&f=false

Comment: Maybe somewhat faster with python: from mpmath import * and then print($\sin(2^{**(10^{**9})})$) gives $0.582846169088576$. mpmath uses libgmp and mfpr (without precomputed pi). On my 16 GB machine print($\sin(2^{**(10^{**10})})$) breaks due to memory errors. What about spigot algorithms?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault With your point that we are simply getting the tail bits of 1/pi, I found that I was doing division poorly (repeating mod pi, which effectively divides one bit at a time), thank you. By fixing that, I gained a 20x speed up (I edited my question to use my new timings), For the record, you are still 2x faster than me at inverting numbers and 3x faster than me at calculating pi.